# Fluently updating an existing one to one relationship with Eloquent in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a one-to-one relationship between my `User` model and an additional `UserInformation` model in which I store additional needed information which would bloat the "normal" user table.

I set up my models like this:

```
# User.php

public function information()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserInformation::class);
}

# UserInformation.php

public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I have a profile page where the User can update information from both tables.

The view has inputs like this:

```
<input name="email"> // is a field in the users-table
<input name="information[size]"> // is a field in the users-information table
```

I read in different locations that I should be able to save both my `User` model and its relation in with:

```
$user->fill($request->all())->save();
```

But this throws the following error:

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

So my current solution looks like this:

```
auth()->user()
      ->fill($request->except('information'))
      ->save();

auth()->user()
      ->information
      ->fill($request->input('information'))
      ->save();
```

That works very good but doesn't look good in my opinion. So my question is: how can I clean that code up and save both in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including this

```
protected $guarded = array('information');
```

in your `User.php` model file

and then

```
auth()->user()
      ->fill($request->all())
      ->information->fill($request->input('information'))
      ->save();
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the `User` model never gets saved. Switching out my `except` method with the `guarded` attribute is working, but I think except looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current solution looks fine, but if you want, you could always extract it out to your own custom method in your User model.

```
public function saveWithInformation($attributes)
{
    $this->fill($attributes)->save();
    $this->information->fill($attributes['information'])->save();
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
auth()->user()->saveWithInformation($request->all());
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks you for that, I'm aware I could just extract this part of my code into a new function, unfortunately that is not the kind of flexibility I was looking for since it isn't very reusable. Since I couldn't find a solution within the framework I came up with my own solution which I posted as answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was looking for a pretty flexible solution I came up with this function which I implemented into my `User` model (but it could also be included in a `BaseModel`)

```
public function fillWithRelation(array $request)
{
    foreach ($request as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) && method_exists($this, $key))
        // check if the value is an array and if a method with the name of
        // the key exists (which would be the relationship
        {
            $this->{$key}->fill($value);
            unset($request[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $this->fill($request);
}
```

This is definitely working if you include the information for a `hasOne` relationship like posted in my question.